# Firebase Storage : Get the token of the URL

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-storage

I currently have an application that works with Firebase.

I repeatedly load profile pictures. However the link is quite long, it consumes a certain amount of data. To reduce this load, I would like to put the link in raw and only load the token that is added to the link.

To explain, a link looks like this: “https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fir-development.appspot.com/o/9pGveKDGphYVNTzRE5U3KTpSdpl2?alt=media&token=f408c3be-07d2-4ec2-bad7-acafedf59708”

So I would like to put in gross: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fir-developpement.appspot.com/o/

In continuation: “9pGveKDGphYVNTzRE5U3KTpSdpl2” which is the UID of the user that I recover already and the or my problem this poses: “alt = media & token = f408c3be-07d2-4ec2-bad7-acafedf59708” which adds randomly for each photo .

I would like to get back only this last random piece …

Is it possible ?

Thank you

UP : 01/11 Still no solution

Answer (score 0):

It's not supported to break apart and reassemble download URLs.  You should be treating these strings as if their implementation details might change without warning.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So I can not put the beginning of the URL in raw and add only the token ..? So no possibility of optimization is possible ..?

Comment: You can do whatever you want, but it's not supported and may break in the future.

Comment: Yeah but how can i get the token added .. ?